# I modified vold.fstab and lost access to my SD card

Tags: 2.2-froyo, file-system

## Background:

I have Samsung Galaxy Ace GT-S5830, which has very low internal memory (181 MB).
I have an external micro SD card of 16 GB, but still couldn't install many apps due to insufficient internal memory.

I read on the Internet that if I modify vold.fstab and replace the word "sdcard" with "sdcard2" then my external SD card will act as internal memory.

So I rooted my phone and installed Superuser, but I haven't installed ClockworkMod recovery or any other custom ROM yet.

## Problem Description:

I installed ES File explorer on my SD card and allowed root access to it via Superuser.
I then went to `/system/etc/` from ES file explorer, edited vold.fstab and replaced the word sdcard with sdcard2.

When I restarted my phone the external SD was no longer accessible. ES File Explorer is also gone, so I cannot undo the change that i did. I tried installing ES again from my data connection, but the installation fails (and the phone reboots immediately). I am not able to install any new apps.

I am unable to access my external SD card, so I can't put anything there via PC or via recovery. I tried pressing the power button + home button to go into system recovery mode. I see only these options

> Android system recovery <3e>
>
> - reboot system now
> - apply sdcard:update.zip
> - wipe data/factory reset
> - wipe cache partition

When I try to select the second option, it says "installation aborted" as the SD card is not accessible. I tried to select the 3rd and 4th options, but that didn't help either - I think factory reset will not reset vold.fstab.

I only have the default apps and Superuser now. I somehow need to find a way to get write permission to `/system/etc` or to `/system/etc/vold.fstab`.

Luckily I found "Android Commander". I installed it on my Windows PC and I am able to connect my phone and access the root folder, but I am not able to push a modified vold.fstab to `/system/etc` because  Android Commander says "no Root Access" - It is seeing it as read only.

Can someone let me know how I can edit this file again? I have an original `vold.fstab` on my PC, but I am not able to push it to my phone via Android Commander as Android Commander is seeing it as read only

Is there a way to give root access (aka read-write access) to Android Commander via the Superuser app?

Is there any other way to get write permission to `/system/etc/vold.fstab` so that I can modify it or replace it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about Android Commander, but a simpler way (in my opinion) would be to use ADB. You may have already installed the Android SDK (if not, go [here](http://dl.google.com/android/installer_r22.0.1-windows.exe)). I assume that you don't have modified your System Path.

1. Move your `vold.fstab` to `C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools` or `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools`
2. Go to the `android-sdk` folder, shift+right click on `platform-tools` and choose "Open command prompt here"
3. Next steps depends if you have a custom rom (a) or not (b) (see comments).
4. We take root privilege:

   - a) If your device is 4.0 or above, type `adb root`
   - b) Type `adb shell` then `su`
5. We make `/system` writeable:

   - a) `adb remount`
   - b) `mount -o remount,rw /system` then `exit`
6. `adb push vold.fstab /system`
7. `adb reboot`

This should do the trick.

Comment: `adb root` will only work if 1. the device is running a custom ROM and 2. root to adb is allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Download the Android Debug Bridge from [here](http://androidarea51.com/downloads/adb.zip), and extract the contents (to the same directory).

Connect your device to your computer using the USB cable and open up a command prompt (Windows logo key + R, type `cmd` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>).

Once that is open, type the following commands:

```
cd <entire path to adb.exe file>
adb shell
su

mount -o remount,rw /system 
# if previous doesn't work try:
mount -o rw,remount -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system

exit
exit

adb push <path to original file> /system.etc/vold.fstab
adb reboot
```

That will grant root, mount the system as writeable and then push the original file and overwrite the modified one (and reboot your device).

Comment: Why isn't this working ??

    $ su
    su
    # mount -o remount,rw /system
    mount -o remount,rw /system
    Usage: mount [-r] [-w] [-o options] [-t type] device     directory

Comment: You have an outdated mound command installed. See the edit which will be up in 2 minutes or so :)

Comment: i think the path is /system/etc/vold.fstab
not sysmtem.etc but system/etc

Comment: I'd remove all windows specific info (where to get adb) - it's not related to the problem...